# flyway configuration with http proxy

Tags: flyway, ojdbc

I can connect to an external db: database1 through flyway CLI and list all the schema versions etc.
This database1 connection does not require any custom-proxy in between.

But I have another DB: database2 which I generally connect with custom-proxy in sqlDeveloper.

How do we mention such advanced-proxy configuration in flyway.conf?

As of now, without proxy info in flyway.conf, I am not able to connect to database2 through flyway.

Comment: have you got this solved?